# How to work with vim and paths containing a "+" sign

Tags: matlab, vim

I have a MATLAB project with some folder names starting with a `+` (packages). When I try to open those with vim from the commandline, e.g.

```
vim +mytools/extrema.m
```

I get an error

```
E492: Not an editor command mytools/extrema.m
```

This also happens when I try to load those files from within vim using `:e`. When use `:Explore` I can navigate into the folder and open files there without any problems.

Is there a way to configure vim to be able to handle these paths?

**Note:** In this case I cannot rename the folder as MATLAB packages have to start with a `+` sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the + sign as follows:

```
vim -- +mytools/extrema.m
:e \+mytools/extrema.m
```

The `--` indicates the end of options; otherwise the `+` is interpreted as an option to position the cursor. The second method should tab-complete after the characters `:e \+` have been entered. (Note that `:e +<TAB>` does not tab-complete because `:edit` can optionally take `[++opt]` and `[+cmd]` as arguments.)

See `man vim` and `:help edit` for more details.

**Update**: Try

```
:arga +mytools/extrema.m
:argu 1
```

This method should definitely allow you to tab-complete from within an open Vim session after entering the characters `:arga +`.

`:arga[dd]` adds its arguments to the argument list and `:argu[ment]` edits the [count] argument in the argument list. The argument list can be displayed with `:ar[gs]`, with the current argument in brackets.

The reason that this method works is that `:argadd` does *not* accept standard syntax like `[++opt] [+cmd]`, as opposed to `:edit`.

See `:help arglist` for more details.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. If only the filname tab-completion would work properly. The + part does not tab-complete, but after the first / all files in that folder do complete.

Comment: The `+` part does tab-complete on my system.

Comment: So tabcomplete does work for the first method. The second method (within vim) also gets completions, but it is completed to \\+mytools/extrema.m and then I get E172: Only one filename allowed. The same also happens with no or one \ . Very strange.

Comment: @Marius You're right, the previous second method (edited, now removed) wasn't correct. The `--` option isn't valid for `:e`. On my system, though, I do get tab complete for the (now) second method as described above. Does that work for you?

Comment: The second option does not tab complete for me, but at least I can open those files now.